# помогите расставить знаки припенания и разобрать по синтаксису.

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, синтаксис

народные таланты, умельцы, вдохновенные мастера, каменщики, плотники, штукатуры, мастера резьбы по ганчу, по камню, по дереву, трудились здесь вдалекие минувшие дни, отдавая свой талант созданию бессмертных творений, вызывающих восхищению потомков.

Comment: Помочь поставить начальную прописной? Помочь убрать опечатки?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Народные таланты, умельцы, вдохновенные мастера:(или тире) каменщики, плотники, штукатуры, мастера резьбы по ганчу, по камню, по дереву - трудились здесь в далекие минувшие дни, отдавая свой талант созданию бессмертных творений, вызывающих восхищение потомков.

Предложение повеств., невоскл., простое, двусоставное, распростр., осложнено однородными подлежащими с обобщающими словами (если тире, то осложн. однородными приложениями со значением пояснения), обособленным обстоятельством, выраженным дееприч. оборотом, и обособл. определением, выраж. прич. оборотом.